# crossbrowser css cursor for ondrag (dragdrop allowed) event?

Tags: html, css, drag-and-drop, cursor

In win32 there is system cursor (see below)

[image: this is system cursor for ondrag event taken from delphi IDE]

Is there any way to use this cursor in opera, IE and other browsers, using css?

I've tried everything, the closest is CSS's "cursor:copy", but that is not that what I need.

PS
can't use url() fo cursor style, cause it's completely unsupported by opera browser.

Comment: A URL is the only way to use a custom image. If neither that nor any of the existing cursors are acceptable, then you are stuck.

Comment: @Diodeus seems like you are completely right, but there is a hope for if it is a system's cursor then maybe there's some hacking method to somehow show it.

Comment: You can try to follow the cursor with an image by hooking into mouse events, but that's the best you can do.

Comment: @Diodeus this trick has issue: image lags and snaps behind the real cursor and original cursor is visible

Comment: Hide the real cursor. :)

Comment: @Diodeus do you mean "cursor:none"? that will not help to hide =) P.S. at least in opera

Comment: http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-custom-cursor.html